# How does shift register works as I/O multiplexer

Tags: digital-logic, usb, multiplexer, usb-device

I was checking on eBay for a CNC controller. I came across this unit, which provides 64 buttons. The micro is a 28pin PIC chip but there are 8x [LS165A](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn54ls165a-sp.pdf) IC's on it. I am guessing there is some sort of multiplexing is going on, since the 28 pin PIC can not provide that much of I/O. But I cant figure out what exactly is going on here, I would appreciate if someone can explain a little bit.

[image]

Here is the bottom view. There are not much traces going to the PIC chip that makes me even wonder more!

[image]

Comment: The 74LS165 datasheet pretty much explains it. Each 165 can read 8 inputs (buttons) and transmit them on one pin. Just wire QH to the next chip's SER input to daisy chain them. So for 3 CPU pins connected to SH/LDn, CLK and the last chip's QH, you get 64 inputs, one bit every time you pulse CLK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Study how a shift register works.

What's happening here is that the microcontroller sends out a serial bit stream where each bit position corresponds to one particular shift register output.  The micro sends the clock and data out to the shift register chain, then issues the Strobe pulse which sends the data to the output latches.

This isn't multiplexing.  The data at each output of the shift register is stable and remains stable until changed by the controller.